# Cannot access Django application using Gunicorn and NGINX on Ubuntu 18

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, django, ubuntu-18.04

I cannot access my django application on my public site. I am running Gunicorn with
`gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/webapps/pcfnet/paulcflynn/pcfnet/pcfnet.sock pcfnet.wsgi:application` and my NGINX file looks like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name paulcflynn.net;

    # to avoid any error while fetching fevicon
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /webapps/pcfnet/paulcflynn/pcfnet;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        # communicate via socket file created by Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://unix:/webapps/pcfnet/paulcflynn/pcfnet/pcfnet.sock;
    }
}
```

I am hosting an Ubuntu 18 instance on EC2 and cannot figure out why I am receiving this error. When I curl localhost I get a bad request error 400. Any idea what my configuration is missing?

Comment: First check the nginx error log. Then check your application's log.

Comment: The error log is blank and the access log shows a 400 error.

Comment: Now read the second sentence in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to this so I didn't configure Django to use any logs. Is there another place I should be looking?

Comment: Well, go fix that so that your application is logging.